# Flask update both Table and Plot in one function

Tags: python, flask

I would like to update a table and a plot in python/flask in one function. I handle the update of the table via

```
@app.route('/api/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():

    return {'data': [{"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "hallo", "wert": "123"},
         {"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "dsadsa", "wert": "123"},
         {"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "123", "wert": "123"}]}
```

where I handle the data in html via

```
server: {
          url: '/api/data',
          then: results => results.data,
        },
```

I additionally would like to update a plot. I tried to send the updated plot via

```
@app.route('/api/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():


    e = [{"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "hallo", "wert": "111"},
         {"datum": "1.9.22", "betreff": "dsadsa", "wert": "7"},
         {"datum": "1.2.22", "betreff": "123", "wert": "7"}]

    e_datum = [ee["datum"] for ee in e]
    e_betreff = [ee["betreff"] for ee in e]
    e_wert = [ee["wert"] for ee in e]

    df = pd.DataFrame({
      'Fruit': e_datum,
      'Amount': e_wert,
      'City': e_betreff
   })

    fig = px.bar(df, x='Fruit', y='Amount', color='City', barmode='group')
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    return {'data': [{"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "hallo", "wert": "123"},
         {"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "dsadsa", "wert": "123"},
         {"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "123", "wert": "123"}], "graphJSON" : graphJSON}
```

where I just added teh new plot to teh return statement. The html-part is handled like this:

```
    <div id='chart' class='chart'”></div>


  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var graphs = {{graphJSON | safe}};
  Plotly.plot('chart',graphs,{});
</script>
```

This has no effect on the plot. It does not change. I guess I need to use render_template to update the plot, but then I cannot update my graph simultaneously. How can I update both my table and plot in one function?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to swap some of the code out as JavaScript.

In my example, I use an endpoint that delivers the data in JSON format. With the help of the JavaScript library [DataTables](https://datatables.net), the data is obtained via AJAX and displayed as a table. If the data has been successfully received, it is additionally converted for the diagram within a callback and displayed with the help of Plotly.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask,
    jsonify,
    render_template
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/api/data')
def data():
    data = [
        {"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "hallo", "wert": 123},
        {"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "dsadsa", "wert": 234},
        {"datum": "1.6.22", "betreff": "123", "wert": 345},
        {"datum": "10.6.22", "betreff": "hallo", "wert": 12},
        {"datum": "10.6.22", "betreff": "dsadsa", "wert": 23},
        {"datum": "10.6.22", "betreff": "123", "wert": 34}
    ]
    return jsonify(data=data)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="chart"></div>

    <table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Betreff</td>
          <td>Datum</td>
          <td>Wert</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(url) {

        const table = new DataTable('#table', {
          order: [],
          ajax: url,
          columns: [
              { data: 'betreff' },
              { data: 'datum' },
              { data: 'wert' },
          ],
          initComplete: function(settings, json) {
            const items = json.data;

            // Transformation of the received data.
            const { colors, x } = items.reduce((ctx, item) => {
              const { betreff, datum } = item;
              !ctx.colors.includes(betreff) && ctx.colors.push(betreff);
              !ctx.x.includes(datum) && ctx.x.push(datum);
              return ctx;
            }, { colors: [], x: [] });

            const data = colors.map(clr => {
              const y = x.map(datum => {
                const item = items.find(item => {
                  return item.betreff === clr && item.datum === datum
                });
                return item && item.wert;
              });

              return {
                name: clr,
                type: 'bar',
                x: x,
                y: y
              };
            });

            // Rendering the chart.
            Plotly.react('chart', data, { barmode: 'group' });
          }
        });

      })({{ url_for('data') | tojson }});
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```